# How to draw a line of collection of parallelograms

Tags: c#, collections, drawrectangle

> For reasons of aesthetics, I want to create a line composed of parallelograms like this:

[image]

But it turns out that the OnPaint override event only allows you to draw rectangles:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);

    Rectangle[] rectangles = new Rectangle[]
    {
         new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 30),
         new Rectangle(100, 0, 100, 30),
         new Rectangle(200, 0, 100, 30),
         new Rectangle(300, 0, 100, 30),
         new Rectangle(400, 0, 100, 30),
    };

    e.Graphics.DrawRectangles(new Pen(Brushes.Black), rectangles);
}
```

My problem is that I need to convert the rectangles into parallelograms, and give each one a different color.

Comment: [Graphics.DrawPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawpath(v=vs.110).aspx) / [Graphics.FillPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.fillpath(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: There is also FillPolygon and DrawPolygon!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FillPolygon can do the job:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
  base.OnPaint(e);
  e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);

  int x = 10;
  int y = 10;
  int width = 148;
  int height = 64;
  int lean = 36;
  Color[] colors = new[] { Color.FromArgb(169, 198, 254),
                           Color.FromArgb(226, 112, 112),
                           Color.FromArgb(255, 226, 112),
                           Color.FromArgb(112, 226, 112),
                           Color.FromArgb(165, 142, 170)};

  e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
  for (int i = 0; i < colors.Length; ++i) {
    using (SolidBrush br = new SolidBrush(colors[i])) {
      e.Graphics.FillPolygon(br, new Point[] { new Point(x, y),
                                               new Point(x + lean, y + height),
                                               new Point(x + lean + width, y + height),
                                               new Point(x + width, y)});
      x += width;
    }
  }
}
```